# Youtube: Parameters to change 3D viewing method?

Tags: 3d, youtube-api

I'm looking for Youtube embedded player parameters that allow me to set the 3D viewing method. I can't find such parameters in the Youtube documentation.

Are there perhaps some undocumented parameters? If not, it would be a nice feature for the near future.

The idea is to send people green/magenta anaglyph glasses (instead of red/cyan) and a link to a 3D video. It would be cumbersome for recipients to have to change the setting manually, so I would like to make it as easy as possible, so that chances that the video will be watched are increased.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have this in the iframe player API currently. Can you please submit a feature request using the process described here: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html?

Comment: Thanks, I have just posted the feature request through the appropriate channel.